# How do you uninstall Ubuntu completely and re download windows

Tags: system-installation, windows, uninstall, ubuntu-gnome

I received a computer that has ubuntu gnome installed because the previous owner uninstalled windows 8 and downloaded ubuntu instead. So how do I get Windows back on the computer and Ubuntu off?

Comment: I suspect Microsoft would want you to buy a copy of their Windows operating system; and then install it on the hard drive; taking up the entire drive; by doing so, Ubuntu would disappear

Comment: Check with the previous owner if the computer came with Windows genuine copy pre installed. If yes, ask that person for the license key or find it on the back case of your computer. That can be used for activation. Otherwise, you'll have to do as @pdc said.

Comment: Yep - if the computer has a windows license sticker, you will probably be able to install the version of windows  that the license sticker is for without having to buy a new windows licence. If you don't want to buy a physical Windows disk, getting the ISO to burn your own can be a little tricky. Once you have the disc, just let the windows installer wipe the hard drive during g install and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to get your Windows 8 product key from your BIOS and write it down for future installation. In the terminal type:

```
sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

Which will reveal something like this:

```
MSDMUoDELL  QA09   LOHR#####-#####-#####-#####-#####%
```

You can read other techniques of accomplishing key extraction [here](https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment).

The next step of erasing Ubuntu and installing Windows is documented here: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).